# Print CSS - How to avoid row cutting on the end of the page in long table?

Tags: html, css

I have the following table which generates about 200 rows. These rows are styled using the **@media print CSS** Problem is that generated file contains rows which are cut in the half (see image below).

I would like to ask how to avoid this cutting in the half? (Row which should be cut should be placed on the new page (ideally after the )).

Many thanks for any advice.

[image]

**Code of the template is following:**

```
<table class="content-table">
  <thead class="mdt-heading-meal-type mdt-heading-row">
  <tr>
  <td>
    &nbsp;
  </td>
  <td>
    Breakfast
  </td>
  <td>
    Lunch
  </td>
  <td>
    Dinner
  </td>
  <td>
    Snack
  </td>
  </tr>
  </thead>
  <tfoot>
  <td>Footer</td>
  </tfoot>
  <tbody>
  <!--CONTINENT -->
  <tr ng-repeat-start="row in rowsMeal track by $index" class="mdt-row-country">
    <td class="mdt-col-country-heading" colspan="5">{{row.caption}}</td>
  </tr>
  <!--COUNTRY -->
  <tr ng-repeat-start="country in row.countries" class="mdt-border-line-bottom mdt-row-country">
    <td class="row-padding-1st-level">{{country.caption}}</td>
    <td class="row-padding-price-1st-level"><span>{{reportCurrency.caption}}</span> {{country.breakfast}}</td>
    <td class="row-padding-price-1st-level"><span>{{reportCurrency.caption}}</span> {{country.lunch}}</td>
    <td class="row-padding-price-1st-level"><span>{{reportCurrency.caption}}</span> {{country.dinner}}</td>
    <td class="row-padding-price-1st-level"><span>{{reportCurrency.caption}}</span> {{country.snack}}</td>
  </tr>
  <!--SUBLOCATIONS-->
  <tr ng-repeat-end ng-repeat="sublocation in country.sublocations" class="mdt-border-line-bottom mdt-row-country row-padding-price-1st-level">
    <td class="row-padding-2nd-level">{{sublocation.caption}}</td>
    <td class="row-padding-price-1st-level"><span>{{reportCurrency.caption}}</span> {{sublocation.breakfast}}</td>
    <td class="row-padding-price-1st-level"><span>{{reportCurrency.caption}}</span> {{sublocation.lunch}}</td>
    <td class="row-padding-price-1st-level"><span>{{reportCurrency.caption}}</span> {{sublocation.dinner}}</td>
    <td class="row-padding-price-1st-level"><span>{{reportCurrency.caption}}</span> {{sublocation.snack}}</td>
  </tr>
  <tr ng-repeat-end></tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

CSS for print:

```
/********
 * Print
 ********/

@media print {
  //First of all set all as invisible
  body{
    visibility: hidden;
  }

  #meals-limit-report {
    width: 100%;
    visibility: visible !important;
    top: 0 !important;
    position: absolute !important;
    -webkit-print-color-adjust: exact;
  }

  .mdt-ultra-light-blue {
    background-color: #7ed3f7 !important;
    -webkit-print-color-adjust: exact;
  }
  .mdt-light-blue {
    background-color: #00b5ef !important;
    -webkit-print-color-adjust: exact;
  }
  .mdt-medium-blue {
    background-color: #005c97 !important;
    color: #FFFFFF !important;
    -webkit-print-color-adjust: exact;
  }
  .mdt-blue {
    background-color: #001f4c !important;
    -webkit-print-color-adjust: exact;
  }
  .mdt-white {
    color: #fff !important;
    -webkit-print-color-adjust: exact;
  }
  .mdt-yellow {
    color: #ffce00 !important;
    -webkit-print-color-adjust: exact;
  }
  .mdt-border-line-bottom {
    border-bottom: solid #b1b3b3 1px;
    color: #000;
    -webkit-print-color-adjust: exact;
  }
  .mdt-col-country-heading {
    color: #b0008e !important;
    border-bottom: solid #53565a 2px !important;
    vertical-align: bottom !important;
    -webkit-print-color-adjust: exact;
  }
  .mdt-heading-1-col {
    width: 60% !important;
  }
  .mdt-heading-2-col {
    width: 15% !important;
  }
  .mdt-heading-3-col {
    width: 20% !important;
  }
  .mdt-heading-text-meal {
    margin-left: 55px;
    margin-top: 0;
    position: absolute;
  }
  .mdt-row-country {
    height: 10mm !important;
  }

  table { page-break-inside:auto }
  tr    { page-break-before:always;page-break-inside:avoid; page-break-after:always }
  td    { page-break-inside:avoid; page-break-after:auto }
  thead { display:table-header-group }
  tfoot { display:table-footer-group }
}

@page {
  size: letter portrait;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Is this "cutting in half" at a page break? All browsers measure "a page" differently. In order to get no break in the middle of a table, you will need to make your table break where you want it. Possibly by creating several smaller tables out of the original table.

Comment: Do You mean that I should do it programmatically? For example, the page can contain 20 rows without breaking each 21 is cut. Should I insert the page break after the 20,40th, etc, row? Could You provide some example or JS fiddle please?

Comment: 1 way to stop this breaking in an unwanted area, is to force the table to break where you want it to, then start the table again on a next page. Tricky thing is figuring out where to break the table since all browsers measure pages differently. So you could use CSS page-break-after, where you would like the page to break.